# override adminhtml block and review model

Tags: adminhtml, blocks, magento-1.8, overrides

I am trying to override two class i.e

- `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Review_Edit_Form` and
- `Mage_Review_Model_Resource_Review`

But they are not being override. please help..

The directory structure is:

```
local -->
       Efk --> 
           Adminhtml -->
               Block -->
                    Review -->
                         Edit -->
                             Form.php
               etc -->
                    config.xml
           Review -->
               etc -->
                    config.xml
               Model -->
                    Resource -->
                         Review.php
```

Here are my overrided files:

**etc/modules/Efk_all** (*working fine.. checked in admin panel*)

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <EFk_Review>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </EFk_Review>

        <Efk_Adminhtml>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Efk_Adminhtml>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**local/Efk/Review/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Efk_Review>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </Efk_Review>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <review_resource>
                <rewrite>
                    <review>Efk_Review_Model_Resource_Review</review>
                </rewrite>
            </review_resource>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

**local/Efk/Adminhtml/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Efk_Adminhtml>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </Efk_Adminhtml>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <review_edit_form>Efk_Adminhtml_Block_Review_Edit_Form</review_edit_form>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: I know overriding is not good but it has a big long story why I am still doing this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the class to which I was overriding was calling a method in its parent class with **same name**.

```
return parent::_afterSave();  //calling parent class's _afterSave()
```

So, when I overriden this class with my method `_afterSave()` then I was calling again the overriden class's method instead of the grand parent's class. That was just *double overriding*.

After realizing this I called the grand parent class with name:

```
return Mage_Abstract::_afterSave() //calling grand parent class's _afterSave()
```

As my understanding, I written a blog in which I explained the same issue.

[**Link**](http://kamlekar.wordpress.com/2013/11/22/overriding-block-or-model-in-magento/)

Answer (score 3):

You have a few errors in your rewrites. The following code should work. You do not need the full name after the `<rewrite>` think of it in terms of `Mage::getModel('first/second_part')` with the `<rewrite>` as the `/`

**local/Efk/Review/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Efk_Review>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </Efk_Review>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <review>
                <rewrite>
                    <resource_review>Efk_Review_Model_Resource_Review</resource_review>
                </rewrite>
            </review>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

**local/Efk/Adminhtml/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Efk_Adminhtml>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </Efk_Adminhtml>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <review_edit_form>Efk_Adminhtml_Block_Review_Edit_Form</review_edit_form>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: I had tried the same first then move to the one which I mentioned above :).. not working

Comment: are they both not working or just one?

Comment: both not working..

Comment: I updated my post after reading this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6576092/1577396).. still it is not working.. please check.

Answer (score 0):

app/code/local/Efk/Adminhtml1/Block/Adminhtml/Review/Edit/Form.php

```
<?php
class Efk_Adminhtml1_Block_Adminhtml_Review_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Review_Edit_Form
{
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        parent::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

---

app/code/local/Efk/Adminhtml1/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Efk_Adminhtml1>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </Efk_Adminhtml1>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml1>
                <class>Efk_Adminhtml1_Block</class>
            </adminhtml1>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <review_edit_form>Efk_Adminhtml1_Block_Adminhtml_Review_Edit_Form</review_edit_form>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

---

app/code/local/Efk/Review/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Efk_Review>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </Efk_Review>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <review_resource>
                <rewrite>
                    <review>Efk_Review_Model_Resource_Review</review>
                </rewrite>
            </review_resource>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

---

app/code/local/Efk/Review/Model/Resource/Review.php

```
<?php
class Efk_Review_Model_Resource_Review extends Mage_Review_Model_Resource_Review
{


}
```

---

app/etc/modules/Efk_All.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <EFk_Review>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </EFk_Review>

        <Efk_Adminhtml1>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Efk_Adminhtml1>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: Can you please relate your code to what I have posted above? it is complicated for me to understand. please...

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: do mean to do like this? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nz2uy/). Sorry I am new to overriding stuff. so I can't understand.

Comment: if I do what I mentioned, I am getting this error `Fatal error: Call to a member function getFormData() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\efk\app\code\core\Mage\Review\Block\Form.php on line 42`.

Comment: Sorry, for my poor explanation. Did you try the code which I have provided

Comment: yes, it is giving me the above error.

Comment: Did you use the exact thing what I have provided?

Comment: yes, I copied what you provided.

Comment: I updated my post after reading this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6576092/1577396).. still it is not working.. please check. If I keep `<class>` as you mentioned then I am getting the above error.

Comment: So still both not working?

Comment: no both are not working.. if I remove the original class function methods. then they are working..

Comment: I edited the answer again. Can you check it please

Comment: I suggest you to rename the module name `Adminhtml` to something better. (I have changed it to `Adminhtml1`)

Comment: I did the same.. it is still not working.. maybe I am doing something else wrong.

Comment: Do you have the same folder structure as my code?

Comment: yes.............

Comment: I tested the above code and it's working fine. I think somewhere else the issue. Do you get any error message or just it loads the core classes instead of overridden ones?

Answer (score 0):

We need to combin those two answers :

1. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/11032/46286
2. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/11029/46286

Try to add following to the first answer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <EFk_Review>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </EFk_Review>

        <Efk_Adminhtml1>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Efk_Adminhtml1>
    </modules>
</config>
```